# TypeError: client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my code below, Need solution please help.

Error :

> TypeError: client.commands.get(…).execute is not a function

```
      client.commands.get(command).execute(client, message, args)
    } catch (err) { 
      console.log(err)
      message.reply("I am getting error on using this command")
    }
```

Comment: Make sure your command has a `execute` function.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure your command is actually in the collection. However it seems more likely that you haven't made an execute function in the command file. Example of how you'd do it:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        message.channel.send("Pong!");
    }
}
```